# Java - Search only working for array [0], remaining array items returning "not found"

Tags: arrays, loops, input, methods

In the following method, searching for an item name that is included in the array should return "(item name) was found and its product id is (item array ID)".

This works for item [0], but if any other item name is entered, they return "That product was not found".

```
        private int findProduct() {
            System.out.println("Enter the item to search for:");   
            while (true) {
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                    String itemToFind = getNextStringLineFromUser(); 
                    String searchText = products[i];
                    if (searchText.equals(itemToFind)) {
                        System.out.println(itemToFind + " was found and its product id is " + i);
                    return i;
                }
                System.out.println("That product was not found");
                return -1;
            }    
        }
    }
```

If anyone has an idea of why this issue is happening, I would be very grateful for some advice on how to resolve the problems.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I got you.

The reason why your method is only right when the target is at index 0, is that your method returns -1 when first time not matched, without examining the other array element. (When a method returned, it terminated.)

Modify and check your code, you will see.

```
private int findProduct() {
    System.out.println("Enter the item to search for:");   
    while (true) {
        for (int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            String itemToFind = getNextStringLineFromUser(); 
            String searchText = products[i];
            if (searchText.equals(itemToFind)) {
                System.out.println(itemToFind + " was found and its product id is " + i);
                return i;
            }
            System.out.println("That product was not found"); // line 1
            return -1;  // line 2
        }    
    }
}
```

The line 1 and 2 I commented, should be placed out of the `for-loop`. If you put them at where they are now, they will be run after the above `if-statement` run.

So if the first element of array matches with `itemToFind`, it works normal. When the first element does not match with `itemToFind`, the below line 2 will be run, your method terminates right away at a wrong timing.

The right code should be:

```
private int findProduct() {
    System.out.println("Enter the item to search for:");
    String itemToFind = scanner.nextLine();  // receive the entered string
    for (int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        String searchText = products[i];
        if (searchText.equals(itemToFind)) {  // check if matched
            System.out.println(itemToFind + " was found and its product id is " + i);
            return i; // exit the method
        }
    }
    System.out.println("That product was not found");
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I am still new to this. I am trying to have the method scan an array for the String entered. If the String is found in the array, it Prints the "found" statement and exits the method. If it does not find the item, it prints the "not found" statement and returns -1. It just wont "find" anything other than the first item in the array. There are 5 items in the array. If I enter the String for any item other than the first one (index 0), it prints "not found" message.

Comment: (Note; Code has been edited as I cleaned it up some) For example: If I enter the String for index item [4] (Polo), it should find index item [4] in the array and should print the "found" statement and return the index number (4) to the main call.

Comment: @Tre I have edited my answer. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Trying to learn through online courses doesnt always make things easier without someone to explain the reason why things fail or suceeded

Comment: Your code exits when the method is run. It asks to Enter the item to search for and immediately after states the product was not found and exits. The call for getNextStringLIneFromUser() calls a separate method to bring the scanner.nextLine() in so changing the scanner.nextLine() back to the method call getNextStringLIneFromUser() actually solved the rest of the issue. Thank you again!